# Add multiple pages to theme customizer

Tags: templates, theme-options, theme-customizer

So that theme customizer over at `/wp-admin/customize.php` is pretty cool, but it looks like it only lets you customize one page. Is there any way to add multiple pages or other theme template pages to this customizer?

Comment: What do you mean by "page"? The settings should apply to the whole theme.

Comment: Ah, you can click through the theme links... my mistake, this question is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages cannot be explicitly "added" to the customizer - to view other theme templates, create pages first then click through the site links in the customizer view.